# Creating a custom InputScope for Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, soft-keyboard

Where can I find a tutorial for creating a custom InputScope? I'd like to create a custom keyboard that displays only the numbers 1-9 on the onscreen keybord (no symbols).

Comment: Someone made an app that shows all the different keyboard layouts you can choose from. You can download it here: http://wp7-developer.com/tutorial/what-input-scope-should-you-use-examination-and-demo-application/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot create custom input scope, here are the ones supported [InputScopeNameValue Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputscopenamevalue%28VS.96%29.aspx) there may be one close to what you want - there are ones with numbers e.g. telephone or number.

Comment: It's a pity... I think there should at least be one that is completely numbers only - it is a very common requirement!

Comment: Bah, I agree with @Rodney, I too have a need for numbers only input.

Comment: I wonder what the view on using the Telephone InputScope for numeric (non-telephone) data is? It shows mainly the numbers and a few other chars but looks much better than "Number"

Comment: @DenaliHardtail  how did you get around this finally? I also need an SIP with just numbers and an enter key

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a custom input scope, but you can process key events, see http://www.atleyhunter.com/2010/11/12/making-textbox-numbers-only-for-windows-phone-7/ for how to handle numeric data entry.