# Keyboard Development on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, soft-keyboard

How can i develop a customized keyboard on Windows Phone 7?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a custom InputScope for Windows Phone 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875711/creating-a-custom-inputscope-for-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a custom keyboard. Check out this question asked earlier:

[Creating a custom InputScope for Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875711/creating-a-custom-inputscope-for-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you *could* create a custom keyboard, it would just be **super complicated**.

1. create a popup that contains buttons that do what you want that mimics the keyboard
2. add tap+focus listeners everywhere to handle making your popup visible and invisible like the keyboard
3. spent a year debugging all the little issues that come up

it's *possible*, but the amount of work required to do it would probably not be worth the effort.

Comment: It still wouldn't work for other apps, so it still wouldn't be a functional equivalent.

Comment: true, but the original poster didn't indicate it would be for other apps, or even creating a custom inputscope.

Comment: thanks John, but i want to have a global keyboard for all apps. I want to make a Persian keyboard.

Comment: @JohnGardner you are correct. I want this keyboard only for my app, so it matches the color theme I am using. Mail application does this exactly.

Comment: @gyurisc the built in mail app is using the built in keyboard, it just has the ability to set the theme on it.  making your own keyboard implies making a keyboard that works for every language!